# multipeer connectivity advertiser progress tracking

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I am sending a file using multipeer connectivity in ios7 in this way:

```
[browser invitePeer:key
                              toSession:session
                            withContext:myData
                                timeout:interval];
```

and the other user receives it in this way:

```
- (void) advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser
didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
    withContext:(NSData *)context
 invitationHandler:(void(^)(BOOL accept,
                          MCSession *session))invitationHandler{
```

The problem is that some files are big e.g. 30mb and take a while. I would like to have some kind of progress tracking. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSProgress is passed with the delegate methods

```
– session:didStartReceivingResourceWithName:fromPeer:withProgress:
```

Which can be used to track progress until

```
– session:didFinishReceivingResourceWithName:fromPeer:atURL:withError:
```

is called